# VBA Dowload file from ddos protected website

Tags: vba, excel

Somebody knows how i can get this file with Excel VBA?

https://www.centralbankmalta.org/site/excel/statistics/financial_market_int_rates.xls

I used this code, but now it doesn´t work anymore:

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

URLDownloadToFile 0, "https://www.centralbankmalta.org/site/excel/statistics/financial_market_int_rates.xls", "X:\TESORERIA\07 Prestamos\Préstamos 2016\financial_market_int_rates.xls", 0, 0
```

I have also tried with:

```
Sub download2()

Dim FileNum As Long
Dim FileData() As Byte
Dim WHTTP As Object

mainUrl = "https://www.centralbankmalta.org/"
fileUrl="https://www.centralbankmalta.org/site/excel/statistics/financial_market_int_rates.xls"
filePath = "X:\TESORERIA\07 Prestamos\Préstamos 2016\financial_market_int_rates.xls"

Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")

WHTTP.Open "POST", mainUrl, False
WHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

WHTTP.Open "GET", fileUrl, False
WHTTP.Send

FileData = WHTTP.ResponseBody
Set WHTTP = Nothing

FileNum = FreeFile
Open filePath For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
Close #FileNum

End Sub
```

This code download this information instead the figures
[image]

So i supose that the problem is the ddos protection... or could be that i have updated office 2010 to 365?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Is the DDOS protection an important part of the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, i´m only supose it. I have detailed the question

Comment: Try `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` and `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` instead of `WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1`. BTW your code [works fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlkJc.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
call shell("https://www.centralbankmalta.org/site/excel/statistics/financial_market_int_rates.xls")
```

or

```
call shell("iexplore https://www.centralbankmalta.org/site/excel/statistics/financial_market_int_rates.xls")
```

Would be the most basic ways.  If you need it fancier, you can use the web browser control and give that the URL. That will trigger it to behave the same as the browser would treat it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'd prefer if it's possible no run an instance of IE

Comment: Looks like the server has a redirect on it.  I am not sure how to get around that.